# Amd driver (fglrx) for ubuntu 12.04.5LTS

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati

Begginer here.

I recently downgraded my Ubuntu to 12.04.5LTS because I wanted dual monitor support but my hd4870 cant support AMD drivers and stuff.

Once I downgraded it and tried to install the drivers something like "one or more tools required for installation are not on this system" or something.

I looked online and tried a few solutions but none of them work like.
I don't remember all that I did but these are among them.

Install headers, 32bit lib.

Log

Check if system has the tools required for installation.
fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/3.13.0-61-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your     system unstable. Not recommended.

Comment: This is a wrong advice in this case.  Did you see the card model?

Comment: @Pilot6 hd 4000 on the amd website.Currently downloading ubuntu 12.04 since my mouse cant move in new kernal

Comment: There is the legacy diver there. It can be installed from ppa as in my answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 for 12.04.5?or 12.04?

Comment: I explained already that it can't be installed for 12.04.5 without downgrading kernel and xorg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not install fglrx-legacy drivers, because Ubuntu 12.04.5 has too new Xorg stack.

You can downgrade Xorg by running

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg libgl1-mesa-glx xserver-xorg-input-all
```

You also need to downgrade kernel too. This can be done with

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

Then you will need to boot with kernel 3.2 using grub menu. After that remove all 3.13 kernels using Synaptic.

Then legacy drivers may be installed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
```

After that you will be able to install legacy AMD drivers that support your video card.

Comment: one more question, i heard you could downgrade too in ubuntu 14.04LTS.If i have to do this for 12.04LTS ,would it be better to update to 14.04 LTS?

Comment: No. There is no good way to use old xorg in 14.04

Comment: What does not work? What is the error?

Comment: same error.I posted log ontop

Comment: You need also to downgrade your kernel too.

Comment: what is the code to downgrade the kernel?and is there a version before this where i  dont have to do all this like 12.03LTS or something?

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: Is there a ltsv version before this where I don't have to do all this?

Comment: 12.04 is LTS. It is still supported. If you find somewhere an original 12.04 image, not 12.04.x, then you won't need to downgrade anything. But you will have to install `fglrx-legacy` same way.